# Can't bind view model properly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I want to create client side logging infrastructure using log4javascript. All logs are sent to server. That part works well. I have created WebApi controller to write those log messages on server. The request is the following:

[image: Request Headers]

I have created the following view models:

```
 public class LogEntryViewModel
{
    public string logger { get; set; }
    public int timestamp { get; set; }
    public string level { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string[] message { get; set; }
}

public class LoggerViewModel
{
  public LogEntryViewModel data { get; set; }
  public string layout { get; set; }
}
```

But the problem is that all data in `LogEntryViewModel` is default. Even when I change `public LogEntryViewModel data` to `public JObject data` that results in empty `data` object. I tried to parse Json that request contain and it is correct. What the problem might be here?

EDIT:

When I have changed `Content-Type` to `application/json;charset=UTF-8` The request looks in the following way:

[image: Request #2]

And then I have changed Post method on controller:

```
// POST api/loggerservice
    public void Post([FromBody]LogEntryViewModel log)
    {
        //BL
    }
```

However, still the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Web API, the media type determines how Web API serializes and deserializes the HTTP message body. There is built-in support for XML, JSON, and form-urlencoded data, and you can support additional media types by writing a media formatter.

I think that, based on your content-type (x-www-form-urlencoded), Web Api expects something like: `logger=AjaxLogger&timestamp=1375705087456...` so it can use the serializer for form-urlencoded data.

Since you're sending JSON to the server I would suggest to set the `Content-Type` to **application/json** and use `JSON.stringify` so it can use the JSON serializer for model  binding:

```
data: JSON.stringify({'logger':'AjaxLogger', 'timestamp': '1234568789'})
```

You might want to remove the layout property as well now.

You don't need the `[FromBody]`. This [blogpost](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/) helped me to understand the `[FromBody]` attribute

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I also have `layout` field which is sent as string. Wouldn't that cause problems?

Comment: please see my updated question. I must be missing something but can't figure out what

Comment: No need for `[FromBody]`

Comment: Yes, You're right. The problem was that controler should accept array of my objects not the single object.